# Check for empty cell in a range of #N/A cells

Tags: excel, do-while, vba

I'm looking for a macro to find the row (in twho columns) that contains one of the two criteria: "" or "Productivité".
After finding the first row that contains on of these cells, i'm trying a loop to move down this row. if the next down cell does'nt contain neither "" or "productivité i have to resize my range to add one row to it.

that is the problem. When i'm testing `Do While Not Range(strDépartPlage).Value Is Nothing And Range(strDépartPlage).Offset(, -1).Value <> "productivité"` it's not working because of the first condition `Do While Not Range(strDépartPlage).Value Is Nothing` . And it's due to the fact that the cells contains `#N/A`. How can i deal with that ?

```
Dim strFirstCelVideOuProd As String
Dim rng1erCelVide As Range
Dim rng1erCelProd As Range

Set rng1erCelVide = Range("E3:E60").Find("", Range("E3"))                  
Set rng1erCelProd = Range("D3:D60").Find("productivité", Range("D3"))

If rng1erCelVide.Row < rng1erCelProd.Row Then
     strFirstCelVideOuProd = rng1erCelVide.Address(False, False)
ElseIf rng1erCelVide.Row > rng1erCelProd.Row Then
     strFirstCelVideOuProd = rng1erCelProd.Address(False, False)
End If

Dim strDépartPlage As String
count = 0
strDépartPlage = Range(strFirstCelVideOuProd).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False)


Do While Not Range(strDépartPlage).Value Is Nothing And Range(strDépartPlage).Offset(, -1).Value <> "productivité"
count = count + 1
strDépartPlage = Range(strDépartPlage).Resize(count, 0).Address(False, False)
MsgBox strDépartPlage

Loop
```

[worksheet #N/A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM48Z.jpg)

In other words, I'm trying to extract the range's address between the blank cell and the cell next to the one that contains "Productivité", and the range's address between the cells next to ones that contain "Productivité".
[An explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Lsv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your case, you should add the check for "N/A" using Excel `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA()` function and exclude those cells from the formula, like for example:

```
Do While Not Range(strDépartPlage).Value Is Nothing And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(strDépartPlage) And Range(strDépartPlage).Offset(, -1).Value <> "productivité"
count = count + 1
strDépartPlage = Range(strDépartPlage).Resize(count, 0).Address(False, False)
MsgBox strDépartPlage
Loop
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Actually the first condition create an error : Range(strDépartPlage).Value = Error2042

Comment: Then you may remove that additional condition causing error. The answer is given corresponding to the main issue reflected in the title of your question, so please mark it accepted if it fix that main issue  (check for #N/A#). Should you have additional issues/questions, please post them separately. Thanks and regards,